# invalid parameter in robocopy syntax

Tags: parameters, robocopy

When I try to copy folder from my server to another computer using robocopy and use the parameter /a:-sh in order to enforce the destination folder not to be hidden (because I copy administrative shared folder) my script is: 
Robocopy.exe "\myserver\e$" "c:\destinationfolder" /e /r:2 /w:3 /np /A:-SH

and in my log I see the error
Invalid parameter #7: "/A:-SH"

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
/A-:SH
```

Documentation states that the arguments are `/A+:[RASHCNET]` or `/A-:[RASHCNET]`